# sql server to delete a record and add sum of value on trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have two tables in my database, `bill_datail` and `bill_log`. I want to delete one record from table `bill_log` and after that trigger an action to do something in table `bill_detail`. My code for delete is the following:

```
   DELETE FROM [mydatabase].[dbo].[Bill_Log] 
   WHERE [mydatabase].[dbo].[Bill_Log].[CU_BILL_ID] in 
      (SELECT  
          FROM [mydatabase].[dbo].[Bill_Log],[mydatabase].[dbo].[Bill_Detail]
         where [mydatabase].[dbo].[Bill_Log].bill_id=37 
           and [mydatabase].[dbo].[Bill_Log].bill_id=[mydatabase].[dbo].[CU_Bill_Detail].cu_bill_id
           and [mydatabase].[dbo].[Bill_Detail].Pay_date>20130206
           and [CL_Com_Rec_Description] like '%اoffpage%' 
           and [mydatabase].[dbo].[Bill_Log].amount<0 
           and [mydatabase].[dbo].[Bill_Log].[Com_Act_Date]='2013/02/07')
   go
   CREATE TRIGGER   [mydatabase].[dbo].[Bill_Log]
   ON   [mydatabase].[dbo].[Bill_Log]]
   AFTER Delete

   AS 

   ---
   BEGIN

        -- get 'amount' from deleted record and sum it to field 'amount' of bill detail


   END
```

But in delete action I get the following error:

```
'Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
```

And I don't know how to fix the error and do the second part.

Comment: The db will generate a temp-table named `Deleted` (I think) for all rows affected by the `DELETE` statement.  You should be able to query that as a regular table.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: But How

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to get a list of CU_BILL_ID to search. So remove all other fields from inner query and just select CU_BILL_ID.

```
 DELETE FROM [mydatabase].[dbo].[CU_Bill_Log] 
WHERE [mydatabase].[dbo].[CU_Bill_Log].[CU_BILL_ID] in 
  (SELECT cu_bill_id
      FROM [mydatabase].[dbo].[CU_Bill_Detail]
     where Pay_date>13930206)
       and [mydatabase].[dbo].[CU_Bill_Log].cu_bill_id=37 
       and [mydatabase].[dbo].[CU_Bill_Log].cu_bill_id=
       and [mydatabase].[dbo].[CU_Bill_Detail].
       and [CL_Com_Rec_Description] like '%اoffpage%' 
       and [mydatabase].[dbo].[CU_Bill_Log].amount<0 
       and [mydatabase].[dbo].[CU_Bill_Log].[CL_Com_Act_Date]='2013/02/07'
 go
```

Try this please.

Comment: the important part of my question is the condition inside the select

Comment: You can put any condition in the select, all that is required here is to select only one COLUMN to compare against. Or may be I am missing something from your question.

Comment: Thanks but It deletes all [mydatabase].[dbo].[CU_Bill_Log].cu_bill_id=37 I only want some of the recordes with bill_id 37 to be deleted, I tried other fields instead of [mydatabase].[dbo].[CU_Bill_Log].[CU_BILL_ID] in  but it didnr word

Comment: But you have applied plenty of other filters as well. You can do one thing. Just run the select statement in separate query window and verify the results you want to delete or not.

Comment: @user972 - The actual problem is that the filters are _inside_ the subquery.  Move everything that touches only `cu_bill_log_` **outside** and remove that table from the subquery.

Comment: but it it deletes all records that has id 37 in bill details tables. I want the one with that conditions to be deleted

Comment: Actually, looking at this a little further, you should be able to use `WHERE EXISTS(SELECT...)` instead.  You probably want to clean up the errors in the current version anyways...

Answer (score 0):

if you want use of **"in"** keyword in your main query ,
the subquery must return just one column as result

```
Select ID,F_Name,L_Name
   From Clients
   Where ID in(
               Select ClientID 
               From Orders
               Where OrderNo > 120
              )
```

Comment: Perhaps you could give him an example?